# Correct usage of "the first of which"

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

I am updating my employer's bio due to the launch of a new product, but am unsure of whether or not the following sentence is grammatically correct:
"Dr. Xxx has written and published over 30 books. Her internationally acclaimed flagship book, "xxx", has been translated into 6 languages and has sold over 150,000 copies."

My questions are as follows:
1) Rather than starting a second sentence, should I use a semicolon?
2) Is my placement of commas before/after the book's title correct? I chose to use quotation marks rather than italicize the title because not all platforms allow stylized text.
3) Should I remove the second "has" in the last sentence?

Other ideas on how to more accurately form these sentences are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks good to me, but I'd let others confirm that.

Comment: So what is the question about "the first of which"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine as is, unless this is American rather than British, in which case the comma after the title should go inside the quotation marks.